# Container is Cut Off by margin

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

In my code, I have two components. One is a title component, the other one is a shop container component. I want them to have 15px between them. The title component already has a margin bottom of 24px. Yet, the content of the shop container gets cut off as if there isn't any margin between them. Below, I have my code. How can I make them have 15px between them?

Code:

```
$dialog-title-margin: 0 0 24px

 .dialog-title {
    margin: $dialog-title-margin;
}
    .shop-cont {
      position: absolute;
      top: -2px;
      right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` Will make your component ignore your margins.

The easy solution is to remove it.

If you absolutely need it, adjust your `top: -2px;`:

top: (title height) + 15px

(This solution is only viable if you put both elements in a container with `position: relative`)

Comment: I tried both. The first solution didn't change anything the container got cut off again and the second one made the container clash with a text below it.

Comment: Are both components placed in another container ?
It would be easier to check if you share the composition of your html.

Comment: I can not reach the html itself but yes, they are both placed inside in another component

Comment: Like @KashL. said `position: absolute;` makes the `.shop-cont` hover over other items. Remove everything in the shop block, add `display: flex;` in both blocks, and adjust the margin to `0 0 15px 0`